# How can I shorten a constant name?

Tags: perl, module, constants, perl-module

I have a module `A::B::C::D::E`. In the module I define some constants:

```
use constant {  
    PERSON => 'person',  
    EMPLOYEE => 'employees',  
};
```

I do:

```
our @EXPORT_OK qw / PERSON EMPLOYEE /;
```

I `use` the module in another script and the constants work if I do:

```
A::B::C::D::E::PERSON
```

How can I just use `PERSON` and not have to include the full module name? I am importing `PERSON` in my script but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 8):

`@EXPORT_OK` only marks things as "available for exporting" (assuming you've hooked your module up to [Exporter](https://metacpan.org/pod/Exporter) correctly).  It doesn't export them by default.

In your script, do

```
use A::B::C::D::E qw / PERSON EMPLOYEE /;
```

to import those constants from your module.

**Update:**  It sounds like you haven't hooked up your module to Exporter correctly.  To do that, you include in `A/B/C/D/E.pm` either:

```
use Exporter 5.57 'import'; # v5.57 introduced an exportable import method
```

or

```
use Exporter ();
our @ISA = qw(Exporter); # also include any other base classes you have
```

I prefer the first approach, which doesn't make your package a subclass of Exporter.

Comment: Yes this what I am doing. And it does not work. The function that I have declared as part of `use A::B::C::D::E qw /.../` I working with no issues just fine. Only for the constants I get "...bareword not allowed..." error

Answer (score 2):

You are missing `=` after `our @EXPORT_OK`.

```
our @EXPORT_OK = qw( PERSON EMPLOYEE );
```

Comment: Yes, but the missing `=` would cause a syntax error, so it's almost certainly just a typo in his post rather than his actual problem.